# “Circular dependency detected” error in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets

I am very beginner to Google scripting. Here I need to count the number of times the word "FREE" occurred in my sheet. But my function returns me an error

> **Error**: Circular dependency detected**

(See the attached screen shot.)

What am I doing wrong and how can I fix it?

Please note: I have some merged cells here.

[image]

Comment: Was this answer of use: http://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/60377/29140

Comment: Was this answer of use: http://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/59478/29140

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is happening because you have put the formula inside the range (A1:c6) that you are trying to count the number of "free"'s in.

Put the formula into a cell outside the range.

Comment: Now I am getting `Formula parse error`!. Is there any errors in my formula ?

Comment: I cannot see one from what you have posted - but it's hard to tell with a picture.   But I have just confirmed that   =countif(A8:C12, "Free")   should work.   See here for an example:    https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1yZmgfox3Ns0xWkqCj2kZSK9Q9aaESsv_skTNO9NGCNg/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Did you notice that I have merged cells in between ?

Comment: Yes that worked, the problem was I had put two = signs with the formula. Now its solved.

Answer (score 0):

The formula in cell `B5` (the up-left cell in the B5:C6 merged range) should be `=COUNTIF(A1:C4)`.